# How can I extract a python enum subset without redefining it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

How can I extract a python enum subset without redefining it?

```
from enum import unique, Enum
@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4
```

I *would like* to get an equivalent to `MyDesiredSubset` without having to define it again.

```
@unique
class MyDesiredSubset(Enum):
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4
```

So far I tried something like this, but `MyTrySubset` is broken and the code is ugly.

```
@unique
class MyTrySubset(Enum):
    pass

for item in MyEnum:
    setattr(MyTrySubset, item.name, item.value)
```

Any suggestions how to get `MyDesiredSubset` without redefining it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code won't work - enums are not quite classes:

> ```
> @unique
> class MyEnum(Enum):
>     ONE = 1
>     TWO = 2
>     THREE = 3
>     FOUR = 4
>
> @unique
> class MyTrySubset(Enum):
>     pass
> ```

```
 for item in MyEnum: 
    setattr(MyTrySubset, item.name,     item.value)  # no duplication error by @unique
    setattr(MyTrySubset, item.name+"a", item.value)  # no duplication error by @unique

for s in MyTrySubset:
    print(s)           # no output - at all

for s in MyEnum:
    print(s)           # prints all repr() of all Enum-values defined
```

---

Use the other enum to declare this one (won't compare equal though):

```
@unique
class MyDesiredSubset(Enum):
    THREE = MyEnum.THREE
    FOUR = MyEnum.FOUR
```

or use the fluent approach:

```
MyOther = Enum("MyOther", [(a.name,a.value) for a in MyEnum 
                           if a in [MyEnum.THREE,MyEnum.FOUR]] )
```

If you use [`IntEnum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#enum.IntEnum) instead, you can even compare them:

```
@unique
class MyIntEnum(IntEnum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4

@unique
class MyDesiredIntSubset(IntEnum):
    THREE = MyIntEnum.THREE
    FOUR = MyIntEnum.FOUR

print(MyDesiredSubset.THREE == MyEnum.THREE)       # False
print(MyDesiredIntSubset.THREE == MyIntEnum.THREE) # True 
print(MyDesiredIntSubset.THREE == 3)               # True @Steven Rumbalski
```

Comment: I suppose it should be noted that `print(MyDesiredIntSubset.THREE == 3) # True`.

Comment: This answer much more than what I was looking for but the fluent approach works great.

Comment: Question about the fluent approach; if `MyEnum` subclasses `str` (so that something like `MyEnum('ONE') is MyEnum.ONE` works), then I guess there's no easy way to make sure that the new Enum produced also subclasses `str`?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest defining properties as indicated in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357405/whats-the-most-idiomatic-way-to-make-a-collection-of-enum-enum-in-python):

```py
from enum import unique, Enum
@unique
class MyEnum(Enum):
    ONE = 1
    TWO = 2
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4

    @classmethod
    @property
    def my_desired_subset(self):
        return self.THREE, self.FOUR

    @property
    def is_desired_subset(self):
        return self in self.my_desired_subset
```

And now you can do:

```py
MyEnum.my_desired_subset
```

Comment: I would expect to see get `MyEnum.THREE, MyEnum.FOUR` as the output of `MyEnum.my_desired_subset`, but I get `<property at 0x7ffcbb291860>`. How can I get the former?

Comment: Making it a classmethod should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

Patrick Artner's answer contains what I was looking for looping through an enum with an if statement keeping desired elements.

Just extracted the relevant bits.

```
MySubset = Enum("MySubet", [(a.name, a.value) for a in MyEnum if a.value > 2 ] )
```

Seems to be equivalent to (without the unique decorator):

```
class MySubset(Enum):
    THREE = 3
    FOUR = 4
```